# cakephp find list

Tags: cakephp

Hi I want to be able to generate a list using find so that I can use in select helper. but there is a problem. i want too fetch id,name(first + last). so how can I achieve it. I want first_name and last_name to be joined as name . How can I achieve it.

```
$this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('first_name','last_name','id')));
```

I can't use model filters and callback Please suggest me how can I do it in controllers itself.

Comment: Related for CakePHP 2.X: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35594552/1369473

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this can be done using the `virtualFields` and `displayField` properties in your model.

In your model, define a virtual field for the full name like this:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)'
);
```

If you now set displayField to full_name you should be able to get a list of your users with the `$this->User->find('list')` method which you can use without problems with the Form-helper.

```
public $displayField = 'full_name';
```

... or:

```
public $displayField = 'User.full_name';
```

The id is fetched automatically.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution is to use Cake's Set::combine to build what you need...

```
$users = $this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('first_name','last_name','id')));

$user_list = Set::combine($users, '{n}.User.id', array('{0} {1}', '{n}.User.first_name', '{n}.User.last_name'));
```

Result will look something like:

```
array(
 [2] => 'First Last',
 [5] => 'Bob Jones'
)
```

Here's the documentation link:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::combine

Comment: virtualFields as said below is the way it should be done. keeps that controller skinny.

Comment: VirtualFields may not necessarily be the solution. The question is, do you want to change the structure of the returned data globally to accomodate one controller/action? If not, using Set::combine is probably a better solution. If you need full_name globally, add the virtual field.

Comment: Please note that virtual fields can be defined on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this first go to the model and add this line

```
  public $virtualFields = array('full_name' => 'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name)');
```

and then go to controller file just use the name "full_name" which you put in virtual fields

```
$this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('full_name','id')));
```

It returns name with combined fields

Comment: It is OK to assign `full_name` to `$displayField` and do a `find('list')`, although, your solution also gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on Tim's answer, however, if you *need* an alternative, teknoid wrote a nice article about this a long time ago:

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/04/findlist-with-three-or-combined-fields/

Comment: The link is broken and the answer doesn't quote anything from the article.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Set::combine was the way to go, since I had to deal with concatenation of fields in associated models, like:

```
$bancos_enteros = $this->Financiacion->Banco->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('Empresa.codigo_contable','Empresa.nombre_corto', 'Banco.id'),
  'order' => array('Empresa.codigo_contable' => 'asc'),
  'recursive' => 1
));
$bancos = Set::combine(
   $bancos_enteros,
   '{n}.Banco.id',
    array(
       '{0} {1}',
       '{n}.Empresa.codigo_contable',
       '{n}.Empresa.nombre_corto'
     )
 );
```

returning

```
    array(
    (int) 14 => '57200002 Caixa',
    (int) 15 => '57200003 Sabadell',
    (int) 3 => '57200005 BBVA',
    (int) 16 => '57200006 Deutsche Bank',
    (int) 17 => '57200007 Popular',
    (int) 18 => '57200009 March',
    (int) 26 => '57200010 Bankinter',
    (int) 4 => '57200011 Santander'
)
```

While

```
$this->Financiacion->Banco->Empresa->virtualFields = array(
    'codigo_nombre' => 'CONCAT(Empresa.codigo_contable,Empresa.nombre_corto)'
);
$this->Financiacion->Banco->virtualFields['codigo_nombre'] =  $this->Financiacion->Banco->Empresa->virtualFields['codigo_nombre'];
$bancos = $this->Financiacion->Banco->find('list', array(
   'fields' => array('Banco.id','Banco.codigo_nombre'),
   'order' => array('Banco.codigo_nombre' => 'asc'),
   'recursive' => 1
    )   
);
```

returns a SQL error in a following query if I don't delete the virtual fields first:

```
unset($this->Financiacion->Banco->Empresa->virtualFields);
unset($this->Financiacion->Banco->virtualFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update for CakePHP 4x.

```php
// Model/Entity/{entityName}.php
// "fname, lname, email" are my DB field names
protected function _getFullName()
{
    return $this->_fields['fname'] . ' ' . $this->_fields['lname'];
}

protected function _getLabelDropdown()
{
    return $this->_fields['fname'] . ' ' . $this->_fields['lname'] . ' (' . $this->_fields['email'] . ')';
}

...


// Model/Table/{tableName}.php
public function getUserList()
{
    return $this->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'uuid',
        'valueField' => function ($user) {
            return $user->get('full_name'); // It's _getFullName()
            // or 
            // return $user->get('label_dropdown'); // It's _getLabelDropdown()
        }
    ])->where([
        'is_delete' => 0,
        'is_active' => 1,
    ]);
}

// Controller/{ControllerName}.php
public function add()
{
  ...

  $this->set('user_list', $this->Users->getUserList());

  ...
}

// View
<?= $this->Form->control('role_uuid', [
   'options' => $user_list,
   'class' => 'form-select',
   'id' => 'user_uuid',
   'label' => __('Choose User'),
   'default' => DEFAULT_USER
]); ?>
```

Read more: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#customize-key-value-output

Hope it help.