# Cakephp find('list') with summarized data returns nulls

Tags: mysql, list, cakephp, find, sum

I have the following query in a Cakephp 2.4 model:

> `$scores = $this->WorkInfo->find('list', array(
>           'conditions' => array('WorkInfo.work_id' => $work_ids),
>           'fields' => array('WorkInfo.date', 'SUM(WorkInfo.score)'),
>           'group' => array('WorkInfo.date')
>       ));`

Which generates the following query:

```
SELECT 
  `WorkInfo`.`date`, 
   SUM(`WorkInfo`.`score`) 
FROM 
   `home`.`work_infos` AS `WorkInfo` 
WHERE 
   `WorkInfo`.`work_id` IN (4, 7, 8, 12, 9, 11, 13, 10, 14, 6, 5) 
GROUP BY 
   `WorkInfo`.`date`
```

The result I get in my application is:

> '2014-03-24' => null
>     '2014-03-25' => null
>     '2014-03-26' => null
>     '2014-03-27' => null
>     '2014-03-28' => null
>     '2014-03-31' => null

While the result I get from pasting this very query in the mysql console is:

> '2014-03-24' => 0
>     '2014-03-25' => 36
>     '2014-03-26' => 0
>     '2014-03-27' => 164
>     '2014-03-28' => 0
>     '2014-03-31' => 0

What is going on here? It is supposed that same queries output same results, isn't it?

I have read something about creating virtual fields for this, but I do not want to overkill, it should be possible to perform a simple aggregation query through Cakephp using the find function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sadly, I think what you want to do can't be done as you want to do it.

Let's see, you use the `find('list')` method, so that's [here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Model.html#2839) in the API. Code looks normal, and as you said, query is ok, returns everything you want. Problem is in line 2883

```
return Hash::combine($results, $query['list']['keyPath'], $query['list']['valuePath'], $query['list']['groupPath']);
```

That line organizes the returned array after the query is done. And seeing [the doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3acombine) for that function, we have

> Creates an associative array using a $keyPath as the path to build its
>   keys, and optionally $valuePath as path to get the values. If
>   $valuePath is not specified, or doesn’t match anything, values will be
>   initialized to null.

Which is what happens to you. Now, debugging, the query result *before* applying the `Hash::combine` function is something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [WorkInfo] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-04-01
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SUM(`WorkInfo`.`score`)] => 24
                )

        )

)
```

so you see, you get the results. And the respective `Hash::combine`

```
Array
(
    [groupPath] => 
    [valuePath] => {n}.SUM(WorkInfo.score)
    [keyPath] => {n}.WorkInfo.date
)
```

which probably causes problem with the dot inside the parenthesis. And the combine function doesn't find the valuePath, and you get null, and you get sad.

If you change your query to `'SUM(WorkInfo.score) AS score'` (leaving everything as is), you have almost the same problem with valuePath

```
Array
(
    [groupPath] => 
    [valuePath] => {n}.SUM(WorkInfo.score) as score
    [keyPath] => {n}.WorkInfo.date
)

 //respective result array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [WorkInfo] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-04-01
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [score] => 24
                )

        )

)
```

You might think that doing `'SUM(score) AS score'` (without the dot) will solve it, but the code of `find('list')` adds the alias if it doesn't find a dot (in line 2865).

So... I guess what I'm saying is: do a virtual field, or listen to Isaac Rajaei, or create a [custom find function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types). But with `find('list')` and `SUM()` you won't have luck :(

Comment: Wow! Awesome explanation. I'd already tried the "as score" you mention, with the results you explain. Thank you very much. I think this issue is something on which Cakephp developers should focus for next releases. I guess I will use find('all'), as Isaac Rajaei advises, but at least now I know why I can't do it my way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$scores = $this->WorkInfo->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('work_id' => $work_ids),
          'fields' => array('date', 'SUM(score) AS score'),
          'group' => array('date')
      ));
```

then with Set::combine you can format your array [cakephp find list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785795/cakephp-find-list)

```
$scores = Set::combine($scores, '{n}.WorkInfo.date', '{n}.0.score');
```

prints=>

```
'2014-03-24' => 0
'2014-03-25' => 36
'2014-03-26' => 0
'2014-03-27' => 164
'2014-03-28' => 0
'2014-03-31' => 0
```

Comment: I want to stick to find('list'). I have seen this solution elsewhere, but with list I don't need to postprocess the data. Thanks for your response